# Using Rxjs map and filter together to select country and states from json

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a json file that contains both countries and states (as a sample):

```
 {
  "countries": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "United States"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "India"
    }],
  "states": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "countryId": 1,
      "name": "Alabama"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "countryId": 1,
      "name": "Alaska"
    } ] }
```

Now I have a Service to get the countries and states to later show in my dropdowns:

```
export class CountriesService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getCountries(): Observable<Country[]> {

    return this.http.get<Country[]>("assets/data.json").pipe(map(obj => obj["countries"]));

  }

  public getStates(countryId: number): Observable<State[]> {
    return this.http.get<State[]>("assets/data.json").pipe(
      map(res => res["states"]), 
      map(res => { if (res.countryId === countryId) return res;}));

  }
}
```

The `getCountries()` works as expected, returning only the `Countries` but I can't get the specific state based on the `countryId` from my `getStates` method.

It returns nothing.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While the result from the API call is an observable, it is "emitting"an observable if an array due to your map function, not an array of observables. So the second map function you have isn't doing what you would expect. Instead, inside your first map, when you get the states, you can use a method that is on the JavaScript array called filter to for the states down to the ones that have the desired country id.

```
public getStates(countryId: number): Observable<State[]> { return this.http.get<State[]>("assets/data.json").pipe( map(res => res["states"].filter(res => res.countryId === countryId)); }
```

Comment: It is perfect, only note that countryId is an integer so I changed to "res.countryId === +countryId" for the "===" to work

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter it later once you get the data.

```js
export class CountriesService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getCountries(): Observable<Country[]> {
    return this.http.get<Country[]>("assets/data.json").pipe(
      map(obj => obj["countries"]),
    );
  }

  public getStates(countryId: number): Observable<State[]> {
    return this.http.get<State[]>("assets/data.json").pipe(
      map(res => res["states"]), 
      withLatestFrom(of(countryId)),
      map((id, states) => states.filter(state.countryId === id)),
    );
  }
}
```

also you can combine all together to avoid requests for different states because it's still the same data.

```js
export class CountriesService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getCountriesWithStates(): Observable<Country[]> {
    return this.http.get<Country[]>("assets/data.json").pipe(
      map(data => data.countries.map(country => ({
        ...country,
        states: data.states.filter(state => state.countryId === country.id),
      }))),
    );
  }
}

service.getCountriesWithStates().subscribe(countries => {
// countries[0].states[0];
});
```

Comment: I can't combine since I need to get the states based on countries when someone selects a country in the drop down.

Comment: It was just the second option. First one fetches them separately.